# Use of colon (not bind) in SQL select query

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datatable

- Language: VB.Net
- Database: SQLite
- IDE: Visual Studio 2012

I'm parsing a folder and placing the file name - with complete path in to a table.

I'm getting the following error from the Visual Studio debugger:

**Cannot interpret token ':' at position 14**.

The line of code is:

```
rowsFound = Me.Select("FileName = """ + fi.FullName + """")
```

Which evaluates to:

```
rowsFound = Me.Select("FileName = "G:\Dropbox\VirtualDJ\Tracklisting\2008-02-02 11th Birthday.m3u"")
```

Position 14 is the location of the drive letter delimiter in the path.

While not the Primary Key, I'm using the full path/file name as a unique identifier and when rescanning the files, checking to see if the file exists before adding a new DataRow.

I've had no problem prototyping this in Access 2010, but needed to move to VB.net as I can't get an ID3 library to work with VBA. However, not being able to get passed the basic lookup stuff is a bit of a showstopper.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the path with single quotes :

```
Me.Select("FileName = '" + fi.FullName + "'")
```

From your comment you mentioned an `apostrophe` being part of the filename, you need to escape it :

```
Me.Select("FileName = '" + fi.FullName.Replace("'","''") + "'")
```

Comment: Always the obvious - and I thought I'd tried that. My fault for coding on a Sunday!

Comment: An apostrophe is a valid character in a filename on Windows.